# MIPS code doesn't print strings loaded from memory

Tags: assembly, mips

So I am trying to find the maximum and minimum in a user input array, however for some reason my program isn't printing the strings that are loaded by their address at some points, i.e lines 83-85 and lines 91-93

Here's the code:

```
.data
array: .byte 40

output1: .asciiz "\nThe maximum value in array is: "
output2: .asciiz "\nThe minimum value in array is: "

newline: .asciiz "\n"
space: .asciiz " "
max: .word 0
min: .word 0


.text
.globl main

main:
     li $t0, 0
     li $t1, 0
     reader:
            bgt $t0, 36, printArray

            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            move $t2, $v0
            sw $t2, array($t0)
            addi $t0, 4
            b reader
     printArray:
        li $t0, 0 # reintialize counter



        arrayLoop:
            bgt $t0, 36, findMax
            li $v0, 1
            lw $a0, array($t0)
            syscall

            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, space
            syscall

            add $t0, 4
            b arrayLoop
     findMax:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, newline
        syscall
        li $t0, 0 #resetting the counter
        lw $t2, array($t0) #assuming index 0 to be max
        add $t0, 4 #adding 4,so that t3 is at array[1]
        greaterLoop:
            bgt $t0, 36, findMin
            lw $t3, array($t0)
            bgt $t3, $t2, updateMax
            add $t0, 4
            b greaterLoop
        updateMax:
            move $t2, $t3
            sw $t2, max
            add $t0, 4
            b greaterLoop
    findMin:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, newline
        syscall

        li $t0, 0 #resetting the counter
        lw $t2, array($t0) 
        add $t0, 4
        smallerLoop:
            bgt $t0, 36, printMinMax
            lw $t3, array($t0)
            blt $t3, $t2, updateMin
            add $t0, 4
            b smallerLoop
        updateMin:
            move $t2, $t3
            sw $t2, min
            add $t0, 4
            b smallerLoop
        printMinMax:
            **li $v0, 4
            la $a0, output1
            syscall**

            li $v0, 1
            lw $a0, max
            syscall

            **li $v0, 4
            la $a0, output2
            syscall**

            li $v0, 1
            lw $a0, min
            syscall

            li $v0, 10
            syscall
```

The problem occurs in the printMinMax function, where the syscalls for printing strings are done, however no strings are being printed. The strings are saved in data as output1 and output2.

This is a really weird issue and I don't know what's kind wrong as there's no error message as well.

Comment: `.byte 40` allocates a single byte with value `40`, not 40 bytes of space for your array that you probably intended. Thus you are overwriting your messages.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Jester helped me find the error. I had to allocate 40 bytes using .space, not use .byte which is going to allocate value of 40 to one byte.

Thanks a lot!